# Rotationally independent distributions

Tags: probability-distribution

[**Maxwell's theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_theorem) states that multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \sigma^2\mathbf{I})$ is the only distribution of a random vector that is invariant and have independent components after random rotations (orthogonal transformation).

Generally, many distributions are rotationally invariant and it's called **spherically symmetric distributions**. However, any non-normal spherically symmetric distribution has *uncorrelated but dependent* components.

Consequently, I am wondering if there are some distributions of vectors which are not neccessary to be rotationally invariant but have **rotationally independent** components.